# How to change the reference title to bold?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies

I'm new to LaTeX and have a question on modifying the font style of bibliography title.

This is the part of code where I'm giving the reference list in an article:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{devaney1982filtered}
A.~Devaney, ``A filtered backpropagation algorithm for diffraction
  tomography,'' \textit{Ultrasonic imaging}, vol.~4, no.~4, pp. 336--350, 1982.

% etc etc list continues..

\end{thebibliography}
```

I don't have a bibliography file, not using `natbib`.

The journal requires the title "Reference" to be in bold font and size 10.
Presently it is regular 10 font-size, not bold.  The rest should remain as it is  (i.e. in 10 font regular text).

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Since you're using some "journal style", you need to at least provide the community with that. In addition to providing this `\documentclass`, create a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that shows your current usage. It just has to include the document preamble and the bibliography, but in total so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile in order to see the output you're currently having problems with.

Answer (score 3):

For me

```
\renewcommand\refname{\textbf{Reference}}
```

works.

EDIT: Centered

```
\renewcommand\refname{\begin{center}
                        \textbf{Reference}
                      \end{center}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great ! one more quick question though, the title is almost but not quite centered. Can the centering be assured in some way? thanks again!!

Comment: never mind.. works fine.. thanks again though

Comment: @Pavel: Yes... if you supply us with more detail in terms of your document setup. Otherwise it's really just guess-work or hacking.